# How to connect iPhone to Bluetooth device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm developing one centralizing system in that, there's one `Chip/Circuit` that contain bluetooth that can connect iPhone,iPad device.

So what i know is there's two bluetooth that's `MFI(Made For iPhone)` and `BLE 4.0`.

Now i search about to How to connect `bluetooth` from `iPhone` and send message to that `Chip/Circuit`. Means if i send message from iPhone like `@"1"` from iPhone to `Chip/Circuit` that it becomes red line and if i send `@"0"` than it turn into green light.

So what i want to know is Which `Bluetooth` is suitable to this process and How do i achieve this.?

**EDIT:**

I have to send different signal to access other diff device so for that i have to buy different `LightBlue Bean` as @Paulw11 said ? Means I access fan and light from bluetooth so for every fan and light should i buy `LightBlue Bean`.

Comment: You will want to use Core Bluetoth with Bluetooth Low Energy. Have a look at the LightBlue Bean

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to achieve, but typically you would have one Bluetooth chip per device, but you could have one for several devices if they were somehow integrated as chips, such as the Bean, have several digital IO pins - You could have one pin for a light and another for a fan if they were in the same unit.  If you are willing to look at mFI then you could create a HomeKit compatible device and work with Apple that way

Comment: Thax, and i'm using serial connection for connectivity over it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Core Bluetooth** to discover all devices that are discoverable. Then if it matches a name etc then connect to it.

refer this link i hope it help you https://github.com/steprescott/SCPCoreBluetoothManager or https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager.h and also you can use **Multipeer** Connectivity framework

Comment: Multipeerconnectivity won't really apply in this instance - it is for two Apple devices.